# Is there an Acumatica rest API endpoint that I can use to test if there is a connection

Tags: acumatica

I would like to build an integration using the Acumatica REST API. However, before logging in or anything. I would like to know if there is a way to test that the server is up and running.

I've tried logging in and I looked at the swagger.json to look at all the endpoints but I think they require to be logged in.

I would expect a 200 response when the server is up and a 500 when the server is not. 5XX if there is server issues and an error if it is completely down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Test` function that I know of. I would recommend doing a HTTP GET request on the endpoint URL. If the request succeeds it will return the WSDL schema with 200 success code.

[image]

Comment: Awesome I think I can make do with that.